# Facebook SDK Custom Story image not showing on timeline on a mobile device (android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

So I implemented attaching images to a custom story as outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph#add-images-to-actions-and-objects

The method I used is "[Posting with Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph#sharedialog)".

When I view my facebook timeline using a web browser on my desktop, I can see the image that I attached. Everything looks cool.

However, when viewing my facebook timeline using the Facebook app in my Android mobile device, I don't see the picture in my timeline. Just the message and stuff. But, if I attempt to edit the posting on my mobile device, the image is there. Why is this happening?

Mobile timeline, no image:
[image]
Mobile attempt to edit, image is there!:
[image]